How can I get resolution, bit rate, and codec from a video file that has missing metadata?
I have thousands of videos with metadata missing.
Tools like ffprobe and mediainfo rely on that metadata, and even using filebot has't resolved this problem.
How can I process thousands of video files, all in different folders, and get the actual physical data for resolution, bit rate and codec, without relying on any metadata, and then update the video file with the correct metadata?
I have also tried to use filebot to re-scan these already renamed folders of videos, but the nfo files are also missing that key metadata.
Any suggestions?
I am on Windows, but I know enough linux to translate a bash script to batch or python if I need to.

Share the full readout of ffprobe FILE for one such file.
